# Show $\pi(x) \ll \frac{x \log \log x}{\log x}$.

Tags: number-theory

> Show $$\pi(x) \ll \frac{x \log \log x}{\log x}.$$

I was able to show a simpler expression, $$\pi (x) \ll \frac{x}{\log \log x}$$ in hopes of using this to prove the original statement, but I still do not have luck. I will attach the proof of $\pi (x) \ll \frac{x}{\log \log x}$ (to avoid making it too long, I omitted some steps, which I can add if requested).

If $r$ is so that $p_1, \cdots , p_r$ are all primes smaller than $\sqrt{x}$ then we obtain
\begin{align*}
\pi (x) & \leq  2^{r+1} + x\prod_{i=1}^r \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_i} \right) \\ & 
\leq 2^{r+1} + \frac{x}{\log p_r} \\ &
\leq 2^{\log x + 2} + \frac{x}{\log \log x} \\ &
\leq 4 \cdot 2^{\log x} + \frac{x}{\log \log x} \\ &
= O(2 ^{\log x}) + \frac{x}{\log \log x} \\ & 
\leq o\left( \frac{x}{\log \log x} \right) + \frac{x}{\log \log x} \\ & 
= O\left( \frac{x}{\log \log x} \right).
\end{align*}
Thus, $$\pi (x) \ll \frac{x}{\log \log x}.$$

Comment: Please define $r$... is it the amount of primes smaller than $\sqrt x$?

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik Sorry about that! Yes, $r$ is so that $p_1, \cdots , p_r$ are all primes smaller than $\sqrt{x}$.